JHipster not prompting (no questions)
When i run the jhipster command nothing happens - no questions, and the folder is empty.
The guide at https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/ says
To generate your application, type:

jhipster

Answer the questions asked by the generator ...


I've executed jhipster -d for debug but there's nothing more in the output than without it.
My jhipster version is 8.7.0
My node version is v21.6.0
My java version is 22.0.2
Any ideas?

It turned out that there was something wrong with my installation of node.
I had to

delete the existing C:\Program Files\nodejs directory, then
download and execute nvm-setup.exe, then
run nvm install lts.

Now it's working.
